# Power BI custom connector application logs not appearing

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am building a PowerBI custom connector for Zoho with OAuth2 flow using the Power Query SDK for VSCode.
I want to emit debug/trace statements from the connector, and am using the following -

```
logMessage3 = Diagnostics.Trace(TraceLevel.Warning, "TextValueFromNumber", "In Contents", true),
```

But, these logs don't appear in log files in the 'Power BI Desktop Store App\Traces' location. I only see PowerBI generic log statements.
In Visual Studio Projects, there is a flag 'Show User Traces' -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/samples/trippin/8-diagnostics/readme

Is there something similar for VSCode SDK Projects?